# (Discord.py) How to check whether bot is already playing audio in a voice channel?

Tags: python, audio, discord

have created a Discord bot using the Discord.py library.
It plays sounds based on a given command with !sound 
But when it's busy playing a sound, and a new sound is called, I want it to stop, and play the next sound. But I don't know a function that checks whether the bot is already playing a sound?
Does anyone have advice?

Here's my code for playing sounds:

```
@client.command(pass_context= True)
async def sound(ctx, message):
  serverid = ctx.message.guild.id
  newname = str(serverid) + "_" + message + ".mp3" 
  print(newname)
  print(serverid)
  mp3 = message+'.mp3' #take message (soundname) and add .mp3
  mp3 = 'sounds/'+mp3  #Add /sounds folder
  print(mp3)
  if(path.exists(mp3)):#check if file exists
    source = FFmpegPCMAudio(mp3) #set FFMPEG source
    if(ctx.author.voice is None): #check if author is in voice channel
      await ctx.send("Please join a voice channel first!")
      print("Author not in voicechat") 
    else:               #otherwist, get authors voice channel UID
      print("Author in voicechat") 
      channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
      if(ctx.voice_client is None): #check if bot is already in voicechannel
        print("Bot is not connected, connecting...")
        voice = await channel.connect()   #if not -> Connect
        voice.play(source)                #and Play
      else:                               #if already connected
        voice = ctx.voice_client          #get UID of voice channel
        print("Bot is connected to voicechat")
        voice.play(source)                #play without Reconnecting
  else:
    await ctx.send("Uh Oh, That chip does not exist")#if file doesn't exist
  print("-----------------------------------")
```

Comment: "But I don't know a function that checks whether the bot is already playing a sound?" Why not just *remember* that the bot is playing a sound? You know when it started playing a sound (because this is the code that made that happen!) and you presumably know how long the sound lasts. Yes?

Answer (score 1):

Just run [ctx.voice_client.is_playing()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.is_playing), which will return True if the bot is currently playing audio.

```py
@client.command()
async def playingaudio(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
        await ctx.reply("Playing audio :)")
    else:
        await ctx.reply("Nothing is playing")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just stop it like this, I think:

```
try:
    voice_channel = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    voice_channel.stop()
    #run code 
except:
    #run code
```

or check wether the audio is playing or not:

```
import asyncio

async def duration():
    global is_playing
    is_playing = true
    await asyncio.sleep(duration)
    is_playing = false
```

run the function right after you started to play the audio and then check with is_playing if the song is playing.
hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I use pytube to download songs and play, to delete, I had this idea

```
for time in range(yt.length + 1):
print(f"{time} >> {yt.length}")
await sleep(1)
if time == yt.length:
    print("Deletando o arquivo musical")
    os.remove(new_file)
```

What he does?
it counts how many seconds the video has, and loops waiting 1 second each time the song plays, and after the end of the song hits, it deletes the file